# Lower Bound on Multicolor Ramsey Number

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I previously asked a question on the upper bound on multicolor Ramsey Number. I was able to solve that with a hint! I'm currently stuck on finding the lower bound for the following Ramsey Number.
First, define $R(\underbrace{3, 3, \dots, 3}_{2n}) = R_{2n}(3)$.

I need to show that $$R_{2n}(3) > 5^n$$

Any advice or hint on how to proceed with this? I've come across several inequalities involving upper bounds of Ramsey Numbers. I'm a little confused on how to come up with a lower bound in the first place, and use that to answer the question.

Comment: Try reasoning like this [from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3022677/lower-bound-bound-for-the-ramsey-number-r-k3-3-3?rq=1).

Comment: Start [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516810) and induct.